# Javascript removeAttribute() and setAttribute() Method

Tags: javascript, html

Kindly help.

JS

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".test1");

x.forEach(element => {
  element.removeAttribute("class",".test2");
  element.setAttribute("class",".test4");
});
```

Current HTML

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="clearfix test1 test2 test3">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix test1 test2 test3">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently what the JS script does is removing the whole attribute class and its value and assigning/setting a new class with the new value.

I only want to modify 1 class name inside the attribute class

Current HTML Result

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="test4">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="test4">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired HTML Result

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="clearfix test1 test4 test3">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix test1 test4 test3">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am just a newbie, i apologize if i naming them wrongly. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanksss.

Comment: use classList to deal with css class [class list docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Thank you @DavidNithaelTorresLima. This solved it >  element.classList.replace("test2", "test4");